# Should I think about selling my drawings? Am I good enough?

Tags: drawing

I am curious as to whether to think about selling my drawings or not to. The drawings that I have done I've been told look really good and I was wondering about if it would be worth anything. I don't think it will be worth anymore than £5 - £10 as I don't think the are as good as other peoples.

Comment: Welcome to Arts and Crafts.SE. This question is not a good fit for two reasons. It is subjective as you are asking us to critique your work and there is a business element here as well. Neither of which is good for a QA format. Once you get enough reputation your are more than welcome to have these kinds of discussions in [chat].

Comment: We have a Meta topic about the business side of things explaining why we  are not a good fit for those questions: http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/156/are-questions-about-the-business-side-of-selling-your-craft-art-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a spot. Setup a booth. Set a price. Take a shower and brush your teeth. Dress well. And sell!

It's important to go through the actions and learn the process: not only the process of creating your art, but also learning the process of selling your art and and selling who you are.

Just like making art you won't learn how it's done unless you go forth and do it for yourself.

Never question whether your art is good enough.

Instead ask yourself, how do I make my art better.

And you do that through practice.

Set up the booth and practice.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that I needed to go in and start rather than waste time asking questions.